# How is it possible to add rows and columns to a table by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have the following table on my page:

```
<section class="content">

    <div class="box">
    
        <div class="box-header with-border">
    
            <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12 text-end">
                
                    <a href="#" title="Novo Cadastro" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#InsertProduct"> <i class="fa fa-plus">  </i>New </a>
                
                </div>
            </div>  
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
<table class="table table-striped" id="QueryTable">
    
        <thead>
        
            <tr> 
            
                <th>Code: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Name: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Address: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Phone: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Options: </th>
            </tr>
        
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>

              <td>Code: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Name: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Address: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Phone: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Options: </td>

        </tbody>
    
    </table>

</section>
```

I need to insert rows and columns into this table via javascript. I tried something like:

```
 $('#QueryTable').find('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('th').eq(n).after('<th>Test </th>');
   });
```

I also tried

```
$('#QueryTable tr').append('<th>Test</th>')
```

I also tried 02:

```
$('#QueryTable tr').each(function()
{
    $(this).append('<th>Test</th>');
});
```

But these codes did not insert a row or column in my table. How do I add rows and columns by javascript (pure or jquery)?

Comment: It seems like you are missing any rows (`<tr>`) in your table's body. Make sure that the cells (`<td>`) are inside a row (`<tr>`). To append a new column try `$('#QueryTable thead tr').append('<th>Test</th>')`. To insert a row (after the new column has been added) try `$('#QueryTable tbody').append('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>');` something like this (make sure to add your <trs> tho.

Comment: You're only attempting to add a `<th>` element.  Why would that result in an entire column or row?  A column requires a `<th>` but also a `<td>` for every row.  A row requires a '<tr>` and a `<td>` for every column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example. I first fixed your table so that your cells are inside a row:

```js
//adds the new column
$('#QueryTable thead tr').append('<th>Test</th>');

//adds a new cell to all existing rows (this assumes that the newly added column does not exist)
//at initialization
$('#QueryTable tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<td>New Cell</td>');
});

//Adds a new row
$('#QueryTable tbody').append('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="QueryTable">
    
        <thead>
        
            <tr> 
                <th>Code: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Name: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Address: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Phone: </th>
                <th class="text-center">Options: </th>
            </tr>
        
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Code: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Name: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Address: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Phone: </td>
              <td class="text-center">Options: </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    
    </table>
```